# Lower bound on $ \chi(G) $ + $ \chi(G') $

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I am trying to prove that $ 2\sqrt{n} $ $ \leq $  $ \chi(G) $ + $ \chi(G') $. 
My guess is to try squaring both sides. I know that $ \chi(G) $ + $ \chi(G') $ is $ \leq $ n + 1. Here n is number of vertices in G. Somehow use that inquality to get the answer. But then I do not know how to bound $ \chi(G) $ * $ \chi(G') $
Here $ \chi(G) $ is the chromatic number of G, G' is the complement of G

Comment: What is $ \chi (G) $

Comment: chromatic number of G